# Does Creating a Variable to hold a cast Save Overhead

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, casting

When I need to save a big list of my Custom Objects between postbacks on my Asp.Net project, I like to save them in a Session Variable, then Cast them to a List<> in a property
Something like this

```
    public partial class MyPage : Page
    {
         private List<MyStorageObject> MyList
         {
                get {return (List<MyStorageObject>) Session["MySessionString"]; }
                set { Session["MySessionString"] = value; }
         }
    }
```

Then I put a List of my objects in there, and get to call it in a later postback. I think this is a pretty standard way to make objects last longer than the page LifeCycle.

But my question is, when I'm using the List more than once, say I'm going to do a few things with it, I can't help but think every time I access it, it's casting an object to a List<> but if I create a variable it looks like it's avoiding the casting.

```
   private void DoStuffWithMyList()
   {
       var x = MyList;

       //Assuming I'm going to call the list 20 times in my method
       x.first();      // Is this any more efficient / cleaner
       MyList.first(); // Than this?

       //Or do they both get converted into the same thing in the end anyway
   }
```

Comment: Note that the "cost" of a cast is absolutely tiny.  You can be virtually certain that it will not be a bottleneck in an application such as this.  All a cast needs to do is look up the type info of the object and see if it's the same as what you're casting to (so it can throw an exception if the cast is invalid).  That's one memory lookup and a few simple word comparisons.  That's a minuscule amount of time for modern computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the first case (using `x`) you're only accessing the property *once* and then reusing the returned value.

In the second case (using `MyList` multiple times) you'll be looking the value up in the session every time you use it. It's also casting, but that's *likely* to be cheaper than the session lookup.

Fundamentally I'd regard the first version as cleaner, as it makes it clearer that you're trying to reuse the same value several times.

Comment: Aw, cool thanks so much Jon. I was worried this was a newb question. I've been doing it this way for years, but just today started to wonder if it got turned into the same thing in the end product.

Answer (score 1):

Of course avoiding the casting is more efficient.

Why not combine the two?:

```
private List<MyStorageObject> _MyList = null;
private List<MyStorageObject> MyList
     {
            get {
                if (this._MyList == null)
                {
                    this._MyList = (List<MyStorageObject>)Session["MySessionString"];
                }
                return this._MyList;
                }
            set {
                this._MyList = value;
                Session["MySessionString"] = value; 
                }
     }
```

Comment: This assumes that you only have one webserver that the user is hitting.  If you have several, and your session is shared between them, then this could result in reading stale values.

Comment: @Servy: That would be the case for **any** Session-related coding.

Comment: You should be aware of that whenever you're coding around the session, yes.  It's important to know, when consuming code, whether you're using the value of the session you pulled out at the start of the request, or if you're pulling it out "right now".  Putting it in a variable as in the OP's code makes it clear the session is only read from once; this code "hides" that behavior and could make it appear to the reader of the code that it's getting a fresh value.  It's important to avoid such likely cases of confusion where possible.

Comment: @Servy: You are being a bit nit-picky here, wouldn't you say? It's around ten lines of code. A developer would figure out what is going on here in 1 minute. Heck, you can even add a comment to the page explaining what is going on.

Comment: @ShaiCohen You generally shouldn't be needing comments to explain your code.  Whenever possible you should be writing code that can clearly be understood without comments.  That you think a comment is needed is in itself a sign that there is an inherent problem with your code.

Comment: @Servy: Wow. I said that a developer would understand what is going on here just by reading 10 lines of code. I suggested the comments because you mentioned "hiding" behavior. Leave it.